# Reading ENV variable in Angular package

Tags: angular

I have below requirement in angular 6 :-

1. host app
2. packages (package1, package2, package3, ...) and import these packages in main app (add dependency in package.json)

In packages, I need to call external API. I want to keep the API_URL in environment variable and not in the code or some file.

I am not sure, how to do this.

I thought of 2 ways :-

```
Method 1. set env var in main app and read in packages (not sure on how to read env var in package) 
Method 2. set env var in each package
```

I have tried below method (method 2) in package :-

```
1. package.json :- 
    "scripts": {
        ...,
        "packagr": "node ./src/set-env.js && ng-packagr -p ng-package.json" 
    }
    "dependencies": {
        ....,
        "dotenv": "^6.0.0"
    }
    (ran npm install)

2. made .env file and mention API_URL env var (.env is in package root)

3. made set-env.js in package's src dir :- 
    src/set-env.js :- 
    const fs = require('fs');
    require('dotenv').config();
    const targetPath = process.env.environment ? `./src/environments/environment.${process.env.environment}.ts` :  `./src/environments/environment.ts`;
    const envConfigFile = `
    export const environment = {
      production: ${process.env.production},
      mock: ${process.env.mock},
      proxy: '${process.env.proxy}',
      API_URL: '${process.env.API_URL}',
      TIMEOUT_SECONDS: ${process.env.TIMEOUT_SECONDS}
    };
    `
    fs.writeFile(targetPath, envConfigFile, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(`Output generated at ${targetPath}`);
    });

4. src/environments/environment.ts :- 
    export const environment = {
      production: false,
      mock: false,
      proxy: 'rest/',
      API_URL: '',
      TIMEOUT_SECONDS: ''
    };

5. import env vars in app.settings.ts :- 
    src/app/app.settings.ts :- 
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

    export class AppSettings {
       public static API_ENDPOINT = environment.API_URL;
       public static TIMEOUT_SECONDS = environment.TIMEOUT_SECONDS;
    }

6. import app settings in package's service :- 
    import { AppSettings } from './../app.settings';

    @Injectable()
    export class GpCustomersService {

        SERVICE_URL = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT;

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

        getIndex() {
            console.log(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT)
            return this.http.get<GpCustomer[]>(this.SERVICE_URL + '/gp_customers');
        }
    }

7. while packaging (running npm run packagr command), it throws below err :- 
    > <package_name>@1.0.0 packagr /Users/<username>/Projects/angular/<package_name>
    > node ./src/set-env.js && ng-packagr -p ng-package.json

    Output generated at ./src/environments/environment.ts
    Building Angular library
    Generating bundle for <package_name>
    Cleaning bundle build directory
    Processing assets
    Running ngc

    BUILD ERROR
    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<username>/Projects/angular/<package_name>/.ng_pkg_build/<package_name>/ts/<package_name>.js'
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<username>/Projects/angular/<package_name>/.ng_pkg_build/<package_name>/ts/<package_name>.js'

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 111
    npm ERR! <package_name>@1.0.0 packagr: `node ./src/set-env.js && ng-packagr -p ng-package.json`
    npm ERR! Exit status 111
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the <package_name>@1.0.0 packagr script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/<username>/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T06_14_32_413Z-debug.log
```

Can somebody help me to fix this and suggest a best way to do this?